# Finding angle to north on image with three control points

Tags: qgis, azimuth, ground-control, geographiclib

So I am working on some software that geolocates spots on a map taken from a drone. I am having some trouble with the actual geolocation when the map that the program is given is not aligned north.

So what I am trying to do is take the three control points and using them determine at what angle (from the vertical of the image) north is at and then rotate the image by that angle.

What I am currently doing is using GeographicLib (c++ library) to determine the azimuth between two of the control points then the angle in respect to the top of the image of those two and rotating the image by the difference, this has yet to prove correct although i get some numbers close to what they should be if I us the forward azimuth at control Point #2.

I know what the map should look like when aligned as I loaded it into QGIS and rotated it. One other issue is that QGIS seems to have warped it a bit when we overlayed it on a georeferenced image so I do not know if I have to take that into account either.

Comment: Which north? Geodetic north? Magnetic? Grid?

Comment: I am not normally in the GIS field so I do not know, whatever north WGS84 uses as 90N 0W.

Comment: The wrapping will occur unless your triangle sides are exact equivalent of distance between control points expressed in pixels.

Comment: Ya I knew that and will deal with it once I figure out how to determine the angle of rotation so my image is aligned north (90N 0W)

Comment: 3 points it's affine transformation. For rotation 2 points are enough. With 3 points I'd solve the affive 1st. Computed required rotation for 1 line only. It will rotate image around 1st point though

Comment: I know this is almost 5 years old, but did you ever find a solution? I'm trying to do something similar with javascript so that I can show a north arrow with a floor plan image.